# Jackson JSON library: Ignore fields that cause an exception when serializing?

Tags: java, json, exception, jackson, jackson-databind

I've got a get_____ method that will throw an exception when it's called wrong.  (The code was written by someone else and I'm not going to be able to change this part of the problem)

**Is there a way to tell Jackson to try and serialize things, and if an exception occurs to just ignore the field** (i.e., don't serialize the exception-generating field) **and to keep going with the rest of the serialization instead?**

I've seen that there's an option to ignore NULL values when serializing, which is great, but I'm looking specifically for ignoring exceptions after calling a get method.

I'd rather not mark individual fields with @JsonIgnore because sometimes the method works on some objects (in which case I'd like to serialize the result of the successful get method) and on some other objects it doesn't (in which case I'd like to skip the get method).  Plus, it's labor-intensive and I'd rather have a blanket solution.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** after realizing the topic was about "serialization":

You have to create a custom [JsonSerializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html).
I suggest you to extend [StdSerializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/StdSerializer.html) and catch for errors returning `null` (combining this with the parameter to not write nulls).
Probably you can find inspiration looking at [FailingSerializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/impl/FailingSerializer.html).

Basically, I think you should just *override* the `serialize` method of `StdSerializer`, calling `super.serialize` catching all `Exception`s.

Comment: Looks like there's one for serializing (StdSerializer), too, which is good.  Which methods would I have to override?  ("serialize" is the obvious one - are there any others I'd need, or can I get away with just that one?)  How do I tell Jackson to use my custom serializer instead of the default?  I know how to do that for specific classes, but I'd want to replace the default with mine everywhere, right?

Comment: Sorry I edited the answer, 'cause I realized that you were talking about serialization.
I added info on how to write it.
For your last question, probably you can find an answer reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205586/changing-the-default-serialization-behavior-in-jackson)